# Odd Sphere as Sasaki-Einstein manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Odd Spheres $S^{2n-1}$ are [Sasaki-Einstein manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasakian_manifold#Sasaki.E2.80.93Einstein_manifolds). On the Wikipedia page one can find a mention about how we can see it explicitly as an embedding in $\mathbb{C}^n$. However I would like to construct all the relevant forms without using this embedding. How can I do?

In particular, the Reeb vector $\xi$, the contact form $\sigma$ (its dual) and the two forms (real and complex respectively) $\omega$ and $\Omega$ satisfying the following

$$ \xi \lrcorner \omega = \xi \lrcorner \Omega = 0$$

$$ \Omega \wedge \omega = \Omega \wedge \Omega =0 $$
$$\mathrm{vol}_{S^{2n-1}} = \sigma \wedge \omega \wedge \omega = \tfrac{1}{2} \sigma \wedge \Omega \wedge \bar{\Omega}$$

and some differential conditions

$$\mathrm{d}\sigma = 2 \omega$$
$$\mathrm{d}\Omega = 3 i \sigma \wedge \Omega$$
and for the metric

$$\mathrm{d}s^2 = \sigma \otimes \sigma + \mathrm{d}s^2(B_{KE})$$

where $B_{KE}$ is the Kähler-Einstein base.

Comment: In particular I need it for a $5$ -dimensional sphere, but I am curious to see how it works in the general case.

Comment: Ok, I found it in this paper https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103904252